# Repeat FK of same Forign table in Laravel migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

The warehouse has an accounts linked to it as followed

```
Schema::create('warehouses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('title', 32);

    $table->bigInteger('sales_account_id');
    $table->bigInteger('promotions_account_id');
    $table->bigInteger('damages_account_id');

    $table->string('address')->nullable();
    $table->string('phones')->nullable();
    $table->string('fax', 12)->nullable();
    $table->string('email')->nullable();

    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->charset = 'utf8';
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

How can I link sales, promotion and damages accounts to Accounts table in smooth way, like hasOne / hasMany / belongsTo methods??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your

- `sales` table has a primary key `id`
- `promotion` table has a primary key `id`
- `damages` table has a primary key `id`

And each primary key is a `unsigned bigInt` type, first of all you need to change your `warehouses` migration as follows to add foreign keys:

```
Schema::create('warehouses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('title', 32);

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('sales_account_id');//note this line change
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('promotions_account_id');//note this line change
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('damages_account_id');//note this line change

    $table->string('address')->nullable();
    $table->string('phones')->nullable();
    $table->string('fax', 12)->nullable();
    $table->string('email')->nullable();

    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->charset = 'utf8';
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();

    //add foreign keys
    $table->foreign('sales_account_id')->references('id')->on('sales')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->foreign('promotions_account_id')->references('id')->on('promotion')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->foreign('damages_account_id')->references('id')->on('damages')->onUpdate('cascade');
});
```

Once you have your foreign keys defined, you can go on to relate your `Warehouse` model to the other three models via eloquent relationship methods.

Assuming that the relationship between:

- warehouses and sales is ONE TO ONE.
- warehouses and promotion is ONE TO ONE.
- warehouses and damages is ONE TO ONE.

Inside Warehouse model you can define three methods:

```
public function sale()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Sale', 'sales_account_id');
}

public function promotion()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Promotion', 'promotions_account_id');
}

public function damage()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Damage', 'damages_account_id');
}
```

This is just a hint to give you an idea how can you relate models, however, based upon your relationships among tables, the methods might differ.

Once you have correct relationships defined, you eager load any relation like so:

```
$warehouse = \App\Warehouse::with('sale')->get();//for example to eager load warehouses with sales
```

OR

you can load sales once you have warehouse like so:

```
$warehouse = \App\Warehouse::first();
$sale = $warehouse->sale;
```

All case scenarios cannot be defined here as they are immense. However, I hope that this will get you started.

One thing to note, your `promotion` table should be defined as `promotions` so that `Promotion` model can relate to it automatically.

Comment: Thanks.., my foreign table is Accounts, so,
'sales_account_id' is related to Accounts.ID
'promotions_account_id' is related to (another) Accounts.ID
'damages_account_id' is related to (another) Account.ID
So all of them are related to the same Accounts table.